# How to get Apple certificate to sign files?

Tags: macos, certificate, configuration-profiles

I was tasked by my boss to handle new project at work - JAMF to manage our MacOS devices (we are mostly Windows corporation, so it isn't easy).

We bought it, had some training. I want now to use ProfileCreator i found to deploy some settings. Bad thing is, that I don't know, how to get a certificate? I think, I need to become a developer and confirm my identity with Apple, am I correct?

Anyone have a detailed instruction, how to proceed? Sorry, if this is a silly question, but after years with Microsoft OS, this is a little overwhelming.

Comment: Did you refer to documentation by JAMF or contacted JAMF customer support regarding this issue?

Comment: Wow, thank you! This has actually helped me! I used [THIS](https://www.jamf.com/jamf-nation/articles/649/creating-a-signing-certificate-using-jamf-pro-s-built-in-certificate-authority) article.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your question involves support with a 3rd party product, it should typically be taken up with the concerned company. The information should ideally be available in their support document or you should be able to get the desired information via a customer support representative.

The following post on JAMF website should answer your concern:

- [Creating a Signing Certificate using Jamf Pro's Built-in Certificate Authority](https://www.jamf.com/jamf-nation/articles/649/creating-a-signing-certificate-using-jamf-pro-s-built-in-certificate-authority)